# Autenticación en Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autenticación

Desarrollo una aplicación **`Asp.Net`** **`Mvc`**, en la cual los usuarios se autentifican contra **DB** ingresando su Usuario y Contraseña…Hasta aquí todo bien.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi aplicación pueda detectar que existe o no un usuario autenticado?

Por ejemplo si el usuario escribe en el navegador: --**http://www.mi_aplicacion.com/recursos_protegidos**

y este no está autenticado la aplicación puede detectarlo y redirigirlo a la página de **login** ¿?

Lo he estado haciendo de esta forma, en cada uno de los **`actions`** de los controladores pero debe existir una mejor práctica para esto:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
   If(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["NombreUsuario"] == null)
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");

   return View();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un buen enfoque para lo que estás necesitando es hacer uso de "**`Authorization Filter`**" disponible en `AspNet MVC`.

En este enlace puedes ver un muy buen ejemplo: **https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/authorization-filter-mvc/**

Básicamente lo que tendrías que hacer es "**decorar**" tus **`controllers`** o **`actions`** que requieras tengan si o si **autenticación**. O, asegurarlo todo y decorar los permitidos sin **autenticación** con **`allowanonymous`**: http://yagoperez.com/el_filtro_allowanonymous/.

Comment: ok...Gracias Camilo Bernal ...Pruebo y te comento

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es un sistema de autenticación de usuarios simple pero a la vez sólido y efectivo, yo te aconsejo que crees un sistema de login basado en `FormsAuthentication`.

La clase `FormsAuthentication` del espacio de nombres `System.Web.Security`, proporciona una serie de métodos estáticos que interactuan con la configuración establecida en el `Web.config <authentication/>`.

Un ejemplo de lo que te propongo sería algo así:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (this.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Si el usuario está autenticado 
            // retorna la Vista de administración.
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            // Si no, retorna la Vista de Login.
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Admin");
        }
    }
```

Te dejo este enlace [Autenticación de usuarios en ASP.NET MVC - Problemas con web hosting en clúster y balanceo de carga](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/4/15/autenticaci%C3%B3n-de-usuarios-en-aspnet-mvc-problemas-con-web-hosting-en-cl%C3%BAster-y-balanceo-de-carga) donde puedes ver un ejemplo muy bien explicado de autenticación de usuarios en ASP.NET MVC5.